# Python Script to Execute SQL in Loop

Tags: python, pymysql

I am trying to write python script which calls mysql SQL.

I am relying on first query result to run second query. Problem is that it's throwing error.

**Error : cursor2.execute(field_sql,id)**

```
import boto3
import importlib
import psutil
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import subprocess
import sys

rdsConn = pymysql.connect(host = 'XXXX'),
                          db = 'XXXX',
                          user = 'XXXX',
                          password = 'XXXX',
                          charset = 'utf8mb4',
                          cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor1 = rdsConn.cursor()
cursor2 = rdsConn.cursor()


name = 'Test'
sql = "select id from Table1 where name = %s"
cursor1.execute(sql,name)
result = cursor1.fetchall()
for id in result:
    field_sql= "select columnname from  Table2 where id = %s"
    cursor2.execute(field_sql,id)
    fieldresult = cursor2.fetchall()
    for fieldrow in fieldresult:
        print(fieldrow)

cursor1.close()
cursor2.close()
rdsConn.close()
```

Comment: What error exactly? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the results you get from the first query? It returns a dict, so your for loop will be iterating over the keys, but maybe you want the values instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your query uses a dict cursor, so it will return a list of dicts, e.g:

```
[{'id': 1}, {'id': '2'}, ...]
```

Which means your `id`* will be a dict, not a tuple as it would be otherwise. Which means you're passing your arguments to the second query as a dict. If you do so, you need to use named parameters using the `pyformat` style:

```
for rowdict in result:
    field_sql = "select columnname from  Table2 where id = %(id)s"
    cursor2.execute(field_sql, rowdict)
    fieldresult = cursor2.fetchall()
    for fieldrow in fieldresult:
        print(fieldrow)
```

You'll see that the printed `fieldrow`s are also `dict`s.

Also, query parameters should be passed either as dict (named parameters) or as tuple (positional parameters). `pymysql` accepts the form `cursor.execute(sql, "name")`, other dbapi2 connectors don't. The canonical form would be `cursor.execute(sql, ("name",))`.

*btw, you shouldn't use `id` as name, it hides the builtin `id` function